# Bootstrap dialog box on submit direct to specific controller action item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "createForm" }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.Hidden("SortField", info.SortField)
  @Html.Hidden("SortDirection", info.SortDirection)
  @Html.Hidden("CurrentPageIndex", info.CurrentPageIndex)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FormID)

  <div class="modal fade" id="showModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body wrap">
                Body Content
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnActive">SUBMIT</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On submit, it goes to the default POST controller action item. I like to direct it to a specific action item though. Any way to specify what it should be. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spec the action and controller here:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createForm" }))
```